Robot not colliding with any object in mujoco
I am using xml file for the robot in mujoco , this is not colliding with any object and going through each other, any suggestion what I am doing wrong ?
<mujoco model="vx300s">
  <compiler angle="radian" meshdir="assets" texturedir="assets" autolimits="true" />

  <option cone="elliptic" impratio="10" />

  <asset>
    <texture type="2d" file="interbotix_black.png" />
    <material name="black" texture="interbotix_black" />

    <mesh file="base.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="shoulder.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="arm1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="arm2.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="wrist1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="wrist2.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="wrist3.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="finger_left.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="finger_right.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
    <mesh file="tabletop.obj" />
    <texture type="2d" file="small_meta_table_diffuse.png" />
    <material name="table" texture="small_meta_table_diffuse" />
  </asset>

  <default>
    <default class="vx300s">
      <joint axis="0 1 0" />
      <position forcerange="-35 35" />
      <default class="waist">
        <joint axis="0 1 0" range="-3.14158 3.14158" damping="2.86" />
        <position ctrlrange="-3.14158 3.14158" kp="25" />
      </default>
      <default class="shoulder">
        <joint axis="-1 0 0" range="-1 4" armature="0.004" frictionloss="0.06" damping="6.25" />
        <position ctrlrange="-1 4" kp="76" forcerange="-57 57" />
      </default>
      <default class="elbow">
        <joint axis="1 0 0" range="-1 4" armature="0.072" frictionloss="1.74" damping="8.15" />
        <position ctrlrange="-1 4" kp="106" forcerange="-25 25" />
      </default>
      <default class="forearm_roll">
        <joint axis="1 0 0" range="-3.14158 3.14158" armature="0.060" damping="3.07" />
        <position ctrlrange="-3.14158 3.14158" kp="35" forcerange="-10 10" />
      </default>
      <default class="wrist_angle">
        <joint axis="0 -1 0" range="-2.23402 1.8675" damping="1.18" />
        <position ctrlrange="-2.23402 1.8675" kp="8" />
      </default>
      <default class="wrist_rotate">
        <joint axis="0 0 -1" range="-3.14158 3.14158" damping="0.78" />
        <position ctrlrange="-3.14158 3.14158" kp="7" />
      </default>
      <default class="finger">
        <joint type="slide" armature="0.251" damping="10" />
        <position ctrlrange="0.0 0.028" kp="300" />
        <default class="left_finger">
          <joint axis="-1 0 0" range="0 0.028" />
        </default>
        <default class="right_finger">
          <joint axis="-1 0 0" range="-0.028 -0" />
        </default>
      </default>
      <default class="visual">
        <geom type="mesh" contype="1" conaffinity="1" density="0" group="2" material="black" />
      </default>
      <default class="collision">
        <geom group="3" type="mesh" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
        <default class="finger_collision">
          <geom condim="4" solimp="2 1 0.01" solref="0.01 1" friction="1 0.005 0.0001" contype="1"
            conaffinity="1" />
        </default>
      </default>
    </default>
  </default>

  <worldbody>
    <light mode="targetbodycom" target="right/gripper_link" pos="1 0 1" />
    <geom mesh="tabletop" material="table" class="visual" pos="0 0 -.6" quat="1 0 0 1" contype="1"
      conaffinity="1" />

    <body name="left/base_link" childclass="vx300s" pos="-0.375 -0.32 0.25" euler="1.5707963268 0 0">
      <inertial pos="-0.0534774 -0.000562575 0.0205961"
        quat="-0.00292324 0.712517 0.00480387 0.701633" mass="0.0969034"
        diaginertia="0.0071633 0.00602451 0.00169819" />
      <geom class="visual" mesh="base" pos="0 .029508 -.003974" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
      <body name="left/shoulder_link" pos="0 .064933 0">
        <inertial pos="0.000259233 -3.3552e-06 0.0116129" quat="-0.476119 0.476083 0.52279 0.522826"
          mass="0.0798614"
          diaginertia="0.00120156 0.00113744 0.0009388" />
        <joint name="left/waist" class="waist" />
        <geom pos="0 -.033992 -.003974" class="visual" mesh="shoulder" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
        <body name="left/upper_arm_link" pos="0 .040 -.020">
          <inertial pos="0.0206949 4e-10 0.226459" quat="0 0.0728458 0 0.997343" mass="0.0792592"
            diaginertia="0.00911338 0.008925 0.000759317" />
          <joint name="left/shoulder" class="shoulder" />
          <geom pos="0 -.073992 0.016026" class="visual" mesh="arm1" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
          <body name="left/upper_forearm_link" pos="0 0 0.264">
            <inertial pos="0.105723 0 0" quat="-0.000621631 0.704724 0.0105292 0.709403"
              mass="0.0322228"
              diaginertia="0.00144107 0.00134228 0.000152047" />
            <joint name="left/elbow" class="elbow" />
            <geom pos="0.0 -0.073992 -0.247974" class="visual" mesh="arm2" contype="1"
              conaffinity="1" />
            <body name="left/lower_forearm_link" pos="0 0.060 -0.245003">
              <inertial pos="0.0513477 0.00680462 0" quat="-0.702604 -0.0796724 -0.702604 0.0796724"
                mass="0.0414823"
                diaginertia="0.0005911 0.000546493 0.000155707" />
              <joint name="left/forearm_roll" class="forearm_roll" />
              <geom pos="0 -0.133992 -0.002971" class="visual" mesh="wrist1" contype="1"
                conaffinity="1" />
              <body name="left/wrist_link" pos="-0.00005 0.0865 -0.06775">
                <inertial pos="0.046743 -7.6652e-06 0.010565"
                  quat="-0.00100191 0.544586 0.0026583 0.8387"
                  mass="0.0115395" diaginertia="5.45707e-05 4.63101e-05 4.32692e-05" />
                <joint name="left/wrist_angle" class="wrist_angle" />
                <geom pos="0.00005 -0.220492 0.064779" class="visual" mesh="wrist2" contype="1"
                  conaffinity="1" />
                <body name="left/gripper_link" pos="0 -0.0865 -0.02795">
                  <inertial pos="0.0395662 -2.56311e-07 0.00400649"
                    quat="0.62033 0.619916 -0.339682 0.339869"
                    mass="0.0251652" diaginertia="0.000689546 0.000650316 0.000468142" />
                  <joint name="left/wrist_rotate" class="wrist_rotate" />
                  <geom pos="0.00005 -0.133992 0.092729" class="visual" mesh="wrist3" contype="1"
                    conaffinity="1" />
                  <site name="left/pinch" pos="0.1 0 0" size="0.005" rgba="0.6 0.3 0.3 1" group="5" />
                  <body name="left/left_finger_link" pos="-0.000002 0.005 -0.15857">
                    <inertial pos="0.017344 -0.0060692 0" quat="0.449364 0.449364 -0.54596 -0.54596"
                      mass="0.0034796"
                      diaginertia="2.48003e-05 1.417e-05 1.20797e-05" />
                    <joint name="left/left_finger" class="left_finger" />
                    <geom pos="0.000048 -0.138992 0.251299" class="visual" mesh="finger_left"
                      contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
                  </body>
                  <body name="left/right_finger_link" pos="-0.000002 0.005 -0.15857">
                    <inertial pos="0.017344 0.0060692 0" quat="0.44937 -0.44937 0.545955 -0.545955"
                      mass="0.0034796"
                      diaginertia="2.48002e-05 1.417e-05 1.20798e-05" />
                    <joint name="left/right_finger" class="right_finger" />
                    <geom pos="0.000048 -0.138992 0.251299" class="visual" mesh="finger_right"
                      contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
                  </body>
                </body>
              </body>
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
      </body>
    </body>

    <body name="right/base_link" childclass="vx300s" pos="0.375 -0.32 0.25" euler="1.5707963268 0 0">
      <inertial pos="-0.0534774 -0.000562575 0.0205961"
        quat="-0.00292324 0.712517 0.00480387 0.701633" mass="0.0969034"
        diaginertia="0.0071633 0.00602451 0.00169819" />
      <geom class="visual" mesh="base" pos="0 .029508 -.003974" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
      <body name="right/shoulder_link" pos="0 .064933 0">
        <inertial pos="0.000259233 -3.3552e-06 0.0116129" quat="-0.476119 0.476083 0.52279 0.522826"
          mass="0.0798614"
          diaginertia="0.00120156 0.00113744 0.0009388" />
        <joint name="right/waist" class="waist" />
        <geom pos="0 -.033992 -.003974" class="visual" mesh="shoulder" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
        <body name="right/upper_arm_link" pos="0 .040 -.020">
          <inertial pos="0.0206949 4e-10 0.226459" quat="0 0.0728458 0 0.997343" mass="0.0792592"
            diaginertia="0.00911338 0.008925 0.000759317" />
          <joint name="right/shoulder" class="shoulder" />
          <geom pos="0 -.073992 0.016026" class="visual" mesh="arm1" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
          <body name="right/upper_forearm_link" pos="0 0 0.264">
            <inertial pos="0.105723 0 0" quat="-0.000621631 0.704724 0.0105292 0.709403"
              mass="0.0322228"
              diaginertia="0.00144107 0.00134228 0.000152047" />
            <joint name="right/elbow" class="elbow" />
            <geom pos="0.0 -0.073992 -0.247974" class="visual" mesh="arm2" contype="1"
              conaffinity="1" />
            <body name="right/lower_forearm_link" pos="0 0.060 -0.245003">
              <inertial pos="0.0513477 0.00680462 0" quat="-0.702604 -0.0796724 -0.702604 0.0796724"
                mass="0.0414823"
                diaginertia="0.0005911 0.000546493 0.000155707" />
              <joint name="right/forearm_roll" class="forearm_roll" />
              <geom pos="0 -0.133992 -0.002971" class="visual" mesh="wrist1" contype="1"
                conaffinity="1" />
              <body name="right/wrist_link" pos="-0.00005 0.0865 -0.06775">
                <inertial pos="0.046743 -7.6652e-06 0.010565"
                  quat="-0.00100191 0.544586 0.0026583 0.8387"
                  mass="0.0115395" diaginertia="5.45707e-05 4.63101e-05 4.32692e-05" />
                <joint name="right/wrist_angle" class="wrist_angle" />
                <geom pos="0.00005 -0.220492 0.064779" class="visual" mesh="wrist2" contype="1"
                  conaffinity="1" />
                <body name="right/gripper_link" pos="0 -0.0865 -0.02795">
                  <inertial pos="0.0395662 -2.56311e-07 0.00400649"
                    quat="0.62033 0.619916 -0.339682 0.339869"
                    mass="0.0251652" diaginertia="0.000689546 0.000650316 0.000468142" />
                  <joint name="right/wrist_rotate" class="wrist_rotate" />
                  <geom pos="0.00005 -0.133992 0.092729" class="visual" mesh="wrist3" contype="1"
                    conaffinity="1" />
                  <site name="right/pinch" pos="0.1 0 0" size="0.005" rgba="0.6 0.3 0.3 1" group="5" />
                  <body name="right/left_finger_link" pos="-0.000002 0.005 -0.15857">
                    <inertial pos="0.017344 -0.0060692 0" quat="0.449364 0.449364 -0.54596 -0.54596"
                      mass="0.0034796"
                      diaginertia="2.48003e-05 1.417e-05 1.20797e-05" />
                    <joint name="right/left_finger" class="left_finger" />
                    <geom pos="0.000048 -0.138992 0.251299" class="visual" mesh="finger_left"
                      contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
                  </body>
                  <body name="right/right_finger_link" pos="-0.000002 0.005 -0.15857">
                    <inertial pos="0.017344 0.0060692 0" quat="0.44937 -0.44937 0.545955 -0.545955"
                      mass="0.0034796"
                      diaginertia="2.48002e-05 1.417e-05 1.20798e-05" />
                    <joint name="right/right_finger" class="right_finger" />
                    <geom pos="0.000048 -0.138992 0.251299" class="visual" mesh="finger_right"
                      contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
                  </body>
                </body>
              </body>
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
      </body>
    </body>


  </worldbody>

  <equality>
    <joint joint1="left/left_finger" joint2="left/right_finger" polycoef="0 -1 0 0 0" />
    <joint joint1="right/left_finger" joint2="right/right_finger" polycoef="0 -1 0 0 0" />
  </equality>

  <actuator>
    <position class="waist" name="left/waist" joint="left/waist" />
    <position class="shoulder" name="left/shoulder" joint="left/shoulder" />
    <position class="elbow" name="left/elbow" joint="left/elbow" />
    <position class="forearm_roll" name="left/forearm_roll" joint="left/forearm_roll" />
    <position class="wrist_angle" name="left/wrist_angle" joint="left/wrist_angle" />
    <position class="wrist_rotate" name="left/wrist_rotate" joint="left/wrist_rotate" />
    <position class="finger" name="left/gripper" joint="left/left_finger" />

    <position class="waist" name="right/waist" joint="right/waist" />
    <position class="shoulder" name="right/shoulder" joint="right/shoulder" />
    <position class="elbow" name="right/elbow" joint="right/elbow" />
    <position class="forearm_roll" name="right/forearm_roll" joint="right/forearm_roll" />
    <position class="wrist_angle" name="right/wrist_angle" joint="right/wrist_angle" />
    <position class="wrist_rotate" name="right/wrist_rotate" joint="right/wrist_rotate" />
    <position class="finger" name="right/gripper" joint="right/left_finger" />
  </actuator>

  <contact>
    <exclude body1="left/base_link" body2="left/shoulder_link" />
    <exclude body1="right/base_link" body2="right/shoulder_link" />
  </contact>

  <keyframe>
  </keyframe>
</mujoco>

